# Subtracting two NSDate objects

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, nsdate, nstimeinterval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Get time difference in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427151/how-to-get-time-difference-in-iphone)

I´m getting date and time from a JSON feed. I need to find the difference between the date I´m getting from the feed and today´s date and time. Any suggestions how I can do this?

I know I need to subtract the current date with the date I get from the feed, but I don´t know how to do it.

Ex:

Date from feed: `Date: 2011-06-10 15:00:00 +0000`
Today: `Date: 2011-06-10 14:50:00 +0000`

I need to display that the difference is ten minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427151/how-to-get-time-difference-in-iphone

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Create two NSDate objects from the strings using NSDate's `-dateWithString:`, then get the difference of the two NSdate objects using

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the input date to an `NSDate` object before you try and compare.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourJSONDateString];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];

CGFloat minuteDifference = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate] / 60.0;
```

The formatter assumses the UTC offset will always be zero. If this isn't true, see [Microsoft's date format string page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for other format codes you can use.

--

Edit: the `dateWithString` method that everyone else used will be better to use in your situation, but the date formatter is necessary if the date format string you are getting isn't exactly right. I don't think I've ever used an API that sent dates in the correct format, perhaps I'm just unlucky :-(.

Comment: CGFloat is not pointer.

Comment: That's what I get for not writing my answer in Xcode before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

From below code you will get an idea for comparing two `NSDate` objects.

```
NSDate *dateOne = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2011-06-10 15:00:00 +0000"];
NSDate *dateTwo = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2011-06-10 14:50:00 +0000"];

switch ([dateOne compare:dateTwo])
{
    case NSOrderedAscending:
         NSLog(@”NSOrderedAscending”);
         break;
    case NSOrderedSame:
        NSLog(@”NSOrderedSame”);
        break;
    case NSOrderedDescending:
       NSLog(@”NSOrderedDescending”);
       break;
}
```

Comment: Have look to the SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562594/difference-between-two-nsdate-objects-result-also-a-nsdate