# iPhone SDK, Calculating time difference between given time

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I am having trouble calculating time difference. I am getting one time from web service response 18:40:56 in this format. I need to find the current timing of Australia, i have also find that, now how do i subtract the both the timing in hour:minute:second format and display the result.

Comment: This sort of question is not suitable for StackOverflow.  Please read the Date and Time Programming Guide for iOS (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) and update your question with code and specific issues if you still need help afterward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get time difference in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427151/how-to-get-time-difference-in-iphone) and similar to many other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

For calculating difference between 2 times, get the timestamp in seconds of both times, and get the difference:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *myDate = [format dateFromString: myDateAsAStringValue];
```

Now, you convert it to  timestamp:

```
 [myDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Do that with both and sustract them

Answer (score 0):

```
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];

double minutes = timeDifference / 60;

double hours = minutes / 60;

double seconds = timeDifference;

double days = minutes / 1440;

NSLog(@"%.0f, %.0f, %.0f, %.0f", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however i have previously done this, i have one issue to find difference of time, like if i have one time 18:53:10 and another time 14:26:12, so need to find difference between them in hour and minutes.