# NSDate hours since 12pm of current day

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using NSDate to get the current time in UTC. I want to find a way to use that to calculate which time zone is currently 12pm.

I am looking at the NSDate class reference and am not sure what I should use.

Comment: What's your definition of which timezone is currently 12pm? Does this include 12:10pm? 12:40? It's possible that two timezones could be in the 12pm hour since some timezones are offset 30 minutes.

Comment: Yes it includes the whole hour up to 12:59. Hmm I did not know this. What could be done in this situation?

Comment: I was thinking of just calculating the difference, in hours, between 12:00 and the current UTC time and move over that many time zones just for a rough answer.

Comment: Try something first and see what you get. If you get stuck with your solution, update your question with what you have tried and explain the issue you are having.

Comment: Okay, based on my theory, my real question is, how could I compare current time with 12pm of the current day. I only see ways to compare with a set date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427151/how-to-get-time-difference-in-iphone